# Good production values for CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT towards same server

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I hope my question is not too arbitrary: On my production server, I have a page sending an API call to another app on the same server with cURL.

I would like to set appropriate values on `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` then `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` to leave enough time to make sure the request completes in case there are lots of requests, but at the same time I don't want the page to hang in case the API is down or takes too long to respond, which would then result in major lag for all users as a huge line-up would be generated.

The API makes a really quick DB query that returns a small json structure, nothing complicated that takes much time.

Given these specifications, any people could comment on this? I currently have:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
```

**UPDATE**:

- API is brand new and only used by me
- API is the key to get all the data. If the API doesn't work, nothing works and I display an error message
- API is run on each page to get the needed data

Comment: This is very borderline *Primarily Opinion Based*. You'll need to determine this based on the role the API plays, what network conditions exist between you and that API, how historically reliable that API has been so far, what you want your worst-case performance to be and so on…

Comment: I hesitated posting this question for that reason, but thought I had nothing to lose

Comment: CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT: Connection shouldn't take more than a second on the same server. It shouldn't take more than a few ms even.

CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: I would curl the url a few times from the same server to see how long it takes and increase it a bit

Comment: @yuikonnu I'd add some production-level load testing to that, not just optimistic best-case sunny-weather conditions…

Comment: I got a load balancer already, planning on doing stress tests soon. Just worried there's something I'm not thinking about that wouldn't happen in a stress test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have information about the behaviour of that API in order to make an educated decision. It also depends on how that API is used in your code and what behaviour you desire in case of failure.

Consider:

- If you set the value too low, your code will fail if the API takes longer to respond for whatever reason.
- If the API takes longer to respond than ~4 seconds, what does that mean?

  - Is the API down entirely? Then indeed you do not need to wait longer.
  - Is it overloaded? Then would it have responded within *5* second? 6? 10? How long will this overloaded state last? Is it bad to compound it by overloading it more, or is it better to abort your code early and let the API recover?
  - Is there a temporary network hickup? Would that resolve if you made the timeout *5* seconds? 10? 20? How reliable is the network typically?
- Would you prefer your app to be *slow* or *dead* if the API responds slowly for any of the above reasons?
- Can you *guarantee* a certain response time of the API, and if it doesn't keep that guarantee that means it's down?
- What's the target response time for your user facing site?

  Network timeouts are typically between 30 and 120 seconds, which compensates for temporary network issues but is also still within the range of a human. A user's attention typically drifts after a few hundred milliseconds, so you'll want to keep your response time well under one second. However, it's not unusual to have to wait for a website to load for a few seconds.

If you need to tweak such a critical parameter to find the best setting, the pragmatic way to do that is to set it to some initial value, get some measurement tools in place to monitor throughput and response rates, and initiate a stress test that simulates expected production level load. Then you'll see your error and response rates go up or down and can tweak the setting until you have found a value that satisfies your desired constraints.

Comment: Thanks for that useful insight friend! I'll make sure to put that to good use, it fills some gaps I wasn't sure about :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many factors that you need to consider when defining those values. However, 2 seconds is considered acceptable for an HTTP request (first byte). If you manage the server where the HTTP request originates then you also should consider the server resources e.g., memory, CPU, IO, web server configuration. But generally speaking you should consider running traceroute to your end point to better understanding latency-- this will help you define a more accurate timeout values for CURL. And of course, finally you should consider the same resource constraints mentioned earlier for the server for the client if you are initiating many requests from there.

Hope this helps! See blog at: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/how-to/read-traceroute

Comment: Thanks for that! I wasn't sure if a server under load was still connecting and just be slower to send the answer, or not connecting at all!